# Looking for the asymptotic expansion of a bizarre sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, approximation

In a program I am witing, a "side" calculation is related to the evaluation of the sequence $$c_n=\frac{f_{n+2}}{f_{n+1}}\qquad \text{with}\qquad n \geq 1$$ (for which an high accuracy is not required) where, with $a>1$ (this is a real number), $$f_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(x^a+i)}=\frac \pi{a\,(n-1)!}\,\sum _{m=0}^{n-1}  (-1)^m \binom{n-1}{m}(m+1)^{\frac{1}{a}-1} \csc
   \left(\frac{\pi }{a}\right) $$ This does not make much problems except the high cost in terms of computer resources and numerical accuracy issues when $n$ is "large" ($n >40$) when using the formula (I can go further with numerical integration).

**My work**

Being short of ideas, I compared $f_n$ to $g_n$ 
$$g_n=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^a+k)^n}=\frac{\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right) k^{\frac{1}{a}-n} \Gamma
   \left(n-\frac{1}{a}\right)}{\Gamma (n)}$$
and, for given $a$, I was able to numerically evaluate $k$ as a function of $n$. Over limited ranges, it became quite clear that, for a given $a$, $k\approx \alpha + \beta n$. On private, Raymond Manzoni (an MSE user) was able to show that $\color{red}{\lim_{n\to \infty } \, \beta =\frac 1e}$. The problem is, at least to me, less clear for $\lim_{n\to \infty } \,  \alpha$.

Computing 
$$d_n=\frac{g_{n+2}}{g_{n+1}}$$ and expanding for infinitely large values of $n$, I arrived to $$d_n=\frac 1{\beta e}\left(\frac 1n-\frac 3{2n^2} \right)+O\left(\frac 1{n^3} \right)$$ and using the limit previously mentioned
$$d_n=\frac 1n-\frac 3{2n^2} +O\left(\frac 1{n^3} \right)$$ This is not too bad (but not fantatstic) since $a$ does not appear until the very complicated coefficient of $n^{-3}$ while, as one could expect, it plays a non-negligible role as shown below for a few values
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 a & n & c_n & d_n \\
 2 & 10 & 0.0819487 & 0.0850000 \\
 3 & 10 & 0.0824285 & 0.0850000 \\
 4 & 10 & 0.0826615 & 0.0850000 \\
 5 & 10 & 0.0827991 & 0.0850000 \\
 6 & 10 & 0.0828900 & 0.0850000 \\
   &    &         &       \\ 
 2 & 20 & 0.0451284 & 0.0462500 \\
 3 & 20 & 0.0452404 & 0.0462500 \\
 4 & 20 & 0.0452951 & 0.0462500 \\
 5 & 20 & 0.0453276 & 0.0462500 \\
 6 & 20 & 0.0453491 & 0.0462500 \\
   &    &         &       \\ 
 2 & 30 & 0.0311135 & 0.0316667 \\
 3 & 30 & 0.0311600 & 0.0316667 \\
 4 & 30 & 0.0311830 & 0.0316667 \\
 5 & 30 & 0.0311966 & 0.0316667 \\
 6 & 30 & 0.0312056 & 0.0316667 \\
   &    &         &       \\ 
 2 & 40 & 0.0236149 & 0.0240625 \\
 3 & 40 & 0.0237755 & 0.0240625 \\
 4 & 40 & 0.0237605 & 0.0240625 \\
 5 & 40 & 0.0237872 & 0.0240625 \\
 6 & 40 & 0.0237690 & 0.0240625
\end{array}
\right)$$

**My question**

> > How could I do better (probably not using this tricky gymnastic) ?

Any idea and/or suggestion would be more than welcome.

Comment: The integration is over $x$, $dx$ ?!

Comment: @Ahmad. Thanks for pointing it ! Fixed.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "for a given $a$, $k \approx \alpha + \beta n$"?

Comment: @AntonioVargas. $a$ being given, for a given $n$ I solve, for $k$, equation $g_n=f_n$. Then, I plot the resulting $k$ as a function of $n$ and observe $k \approx \alpha + \beta n$. Sorry if the post was not clear. Is this better ?

Comment: Ah I see, that's very clear. Thanks!

Comment: We have $c_n=\dfrac{d_{n+1}}{(n+1)d_n}$ where $$d_n=n!f_{n+1}=\Gamma\left(1+\frac{1}{a}\right)\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{-1/a}e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^n\,dx,$$ to which the [Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) could be applied.

Comment: @metamorphy. Interesting (once more !). Thanks :-)